# Unexpected result from inner table join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables

- sponsor = id(PK), image, link
- sponsor_tier = id(PK), name
- sponsor_tier_rel = id(PK), sponsor_id(FK sponsor table id), sponsor_tier_id(FK sponsor_tier table id)

I do a query like this:

```
$stmt2 = $db_connection->prepare("SELECT
                                    sponsor.image,
                                    sponsor.link
                                FROM
                                    sponsor_tier_rel
                                    INNER JOIN sponsor_tier
                                        ON sponsor_tier_rel.sponsor_tier_id = 8
                                    INNER JOIN sponsor
                                        ON sponsor_tier_rel.sponsor_id = sponsor.id
                                ");
```

and I SHOULD get 10 results (as there are only 10 entries in the sponsor_tier_rel table) but instead I get 80 results with each sponsor_tier_rel entry repeating itself 8 times.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: You have a cross join in your query. sponsor_tier is not joined with anything

Comment: @GurwinderSingh i screwed up bad and over complicated this. Your comment helped

Comment: `SELECT sponsor.image, sponsor.link FROM sponsor_tier_rel INNER JOIN sponsor ON sponsor_tier_rel.sponsor_id = sponsor.id WHERE sponsor_tier_rel.sponsor_tier_id = 8` was all that was needed. If you submit as an answer I will accept @GurwinderSingh

Comment: I was using this post for help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008853/join-two-tables-based-on-relationship-defined-in-third-table and that's why i had the extra INNER JOIN on there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is missing the join condition to `sponsor_tier` table.

```
SELECT
  sponsor.image,
  sponsor.link
FROM
  sponsor_tier_rel
  INNER JOIN sponsor_tier ON sponsor_tier_rel.sponsor_tier_id = 
sponsor_tier.id
  INNER JOIN sponsor ON sponsor_tier_rel.sponsor_id = sponsor.id
WHERE
  sponsor_tier_rel.sponsor_tier_id = 8
```