# How can I get full results in SQL query using 3 tables, where 1 of them keeps relation of 2 another?

Tags: sql, impala, hue

I need help writing a query to display results I want.

"Table 3 - relations" keeps all relations between table 1 and 2.**Often, relation between table 1 and 2 will not exist in table 3** so I want to see missing relation in the results for all Table 1 rows - see expected Results below.
I can't modify these tables - I have only SELECT privilege.

[image]

Data and expected result below:

```
Table 1 - a:
a_id, a_name
e.g.: 
1 A
2 B

Table 2 - b:
b_id, b_name
e.g.: 
1 X
2 Y

Table 3 - relation:
asset1_id (it's always id from Table 1), asset2_id (it's always id from Table 2), relation_type
e.g.: 
1 1 covers
1 2 covers
```

Expected result:

```
Table1_name, Table2_name, Table3_relation_type  (including NULL for b_name and relation_type when such relation does not exist in Table 3 - relation)
e.g.
A X covers
A Y covers
B NULL NULL
```

I can't get the 3rd expected line with NULLs.

Comment: Presumably there are relationships between the tables.  You should explain what they are.

Comment: You have to create unique I'd in all the table and then merge the table by using unique I'd. Use SQL join by creating primary key and foreign key in table and to get data after join these tables.

Comment: I clarified the relations between tables. I cannot modify the tables, I only have SELECT rights.

Comment: Check this, it might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008853/join-two-tables-based-on-relationship-defined-in-third-table

Comment: The article above gives me results without the 3rd line I expect to get - so I still can't see NULL in results, when there is no relation in Tbale 3 for some rows of Table 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this query will produce those results.

```sql
select a.name as a_name,b.name as b_name, r.relation_type from relation r
join a on a.id=r.asset1_id
join b on b.id=r.asset2_id
union 
select a.name as a_name,b.name as b_name,r.relation_type from relation r
full outer join a on a.id=r.asset1_id
full outer join b on b.id=r.asset2_id
where a.id is null or b.id is null
```

Comment: No expected NULLs this way when item from table 1 does not match any Table 3 row via Table 2..

Answer (score 0):

With your data sample you could try this one.

It should work both hive or impala.

```sql
SELECT t1.name ,t2.name ,r.relation_type 
FROM relation r
FULL OUTER JOIN table1 t1 ON(t1.id = r.id1)
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON(t2.id = r.id2);

+------+------+---------------+
| name | name | relation_type |
+------+------+---------------+
| A    | X    | covers        |
| A    | Y    | covers        |
| B    | NULL | NULL          |
+------+------+---------------+
```

Comment: This also doesn't get me the NULL expected. I think it is because there are many relationship types and I only am interested in r.type='Control' and when applying this filter I'm loosing all Table 1 rows with no relation.

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH 
    cte_A AS (
        SELECT id as a_id, name as a_name
        FROM a
        ),
    cte_C AS (
        SELECT c.asset_id1 as a_id, b.name, c.relation
        FROM c
            LEFT JOIN b ON c.id=b.asset_id2
        )

SELECT cte_A.a_name, cte_C.name as c_name, cte_C.relation
FROM cte_A
    LEFT JOIN cte_C ON cte_A.a_id=cte_C.a_id
```

Comment: This works exactly as intended, possibly can be simplified to avoid first cte.